# How does linux know to mount / without /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, systemd, boot, linux-kernel, initramfs

When /etc/fstab gets deleted/name is changed booting into the machine still works, in addition the root file system (/) is still mounted and on the correct storage device, how does it know to mount / on that device without /etc/fstab.

Comment: When i boot / is mounted on the specific LVM that is written in the /etc/fstab, how does the initrd know to mount it on that drive and not another one?

Comment: Please see the Q/A I linked above. The root partition is passed as a parameter to the kernel by the boot loader.

Comment: `/etc/fstab` is on the root file system. The problem can be generalised even more: How does the kernel know where to find `/etc/fstab` - and the answer is of course that the root fs is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Adding to the above comments that, without fstab, the system might well have forgotten... **how** you would like it to be mounted... (I mean your specific mount options (if any))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boot loader passes a root= argument to the kernel when it loads it telling it what to mount as the root filesystem.  /etc/fstab can not be consulted to find this out because the root filesystem where it lives has not yet been mounted.

Back in the ancient times before bootloaders were in widespread use, and the kernel could be directly written to say, a boot floppy, you had to use `rdev` to modify the kernel image so that it was hard coded with which boot device it should mount as the root.